# 階層構造を持ったコンテキストメニューをキーボードで操作する

Tags: c#, wpf

System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuクラスをXAMLではなくC#のコードから生成しています。階層構造は以下のとおりで、カッコ内はバインドされたキーです。

このコンテキストメニューが開いた状態で、B→Aと押すとMenu2-1が実行されるようにしたいのですが、どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。

```
ContextMenu
  Menu1 (A)
  Menu2 (B)
    Menu2-1 (A)
    Menu2-2 (B)
  Menu3 (C)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ご質問の意図として、

1. コンテキストメニューにアクセスキーを指定したい
2. コンテキストメニューにコマンドをバインドして実行したい

のどちらなのか、意図を取りかねましたので分けてご回答いたします。
尚、前提として、

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"/>
```

のような極めて単純なWindowを定義済みとご理解ください。

### コンテキストメニューにアクセスキーを指定したい

に関しては、ContextMenuの中に含ませるMenuItemのHeaderプロパティの中に、以下のように、アンダースコアに続いて、目的のキーを指定することで可能です。

```
var menuItem = new MenuItem {Header = "ファイル(_F)"};
```

### コンテキストメニューにコマンドをバインドして実行したい

この場合、Xamlではなく、CSharpにて定義したいとのことなので、MainWindowのCtorのタイミングでコンテキストメニューを生成して、MainWindowのコンテキストメニューとして登録するなら、以下のようなコードになるかと思います。

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
/// <summary>
///     MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static readonly ICommand ShowMessageCommand = new RoutedCommand("ShowMessageCommand", typeof (MenuItem));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandBinding bind = new CommandBinding(ShowMessageCommand, ShowCommand);


        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();


        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem {Header = "A(_A)", Command = ShowMessageCommand};
        menuItem.CommandBindings.Add(bind);
        contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new MenuItem {Header = "B(_B)"};

        MenuItem subItem = new MenuItem {Header = "A-A(_A)", Command = ShowMessageCommand};
        subItem.CommandBindings.Add(bind);
        menuItem.Items.Add(subItem);

        subItem = new MenuItem {Header = "B-B(_B)", Command = ShowMessageCommand};
        subItem.CommandBindings.Add(bind);
        menuItem.Items.Add(subItem);

        contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);


        menuItem = new MenuItem {Header = "C(_C)", Command = ShowMessageCommand};
        menuItem.CommandBindings.Add(bind);
        contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);

        ContextMenu = contextMenu;
    }


    private void ShowCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;

        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "コンテキストメニューの\"" + item.Header + "\"に対応するコマンドが実行されました。");
        }
    }
}
```

}

上記サンプルでは、RoutedCommandを利用したCommandBindingを利用しておりますが、適宜そこは変更していただければと思います。
また、蛇足ながら、コマンドではなく、特定のイベントに対応した処理をする場合は、MenuItemの当該イベントにイベントハンドラを登録すれば可能です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。不明瞭な質門で申し訳ないです。MenuItemのHeaderプロパティにアンダースコア付きでキーを指定すると、サブ階層を持つアイテムの場合はサブ階層が開く動作になるんですね。ContextMenuのInputBindingsにKeyBindingを設定してみたりしていてそれだとうまく行かなかったのですが、ご提示の方法でうまくいきました。